# How to deploy Python to Windows users?

Tags: python, windows, delphi, deployment, lazarus

I'm soon to launch a [beta app](http://www.bestsellerapp.com/) and this have the option to create custom integration scripts on [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)).

The app will target [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X) and Windows, and my problem is with Windows where Python normally is not present.

My actual aproach is silently run the Python 2.6 install. However I face the problem that is not activated by default and the path is not set when use the [command line options](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5/msi/). And I fear that if Python is installed before and I upgrade to a new version this could break something else...

So, I wonder how this can be done cleanly. Is it OK if I copy the whole Python 2.6 directory, and put it in a sub-directory of my app and install everything there? Or with virtualenv is posible run diferents versions of Python (if Python is already installed in the machine?).

I also play before embedding Python with a DLL, and found it easy but I lost the ability to debug, so I switch to command-line plug-ins.

I execute the plug-ins from command line and read the STDOUT and STDERR output. The app is made with Delphi/Lazarus. I install others modules like JSON and RPC clients, Win32com, ORM, etc. I create the installer with [bitrock](http://bitrock.com/).

UPDATE: The end-users are small business owners, and the Python scripts are made by developers. I want to avoid any additional step in the deployment, so I want a fully integrated setup.

Comment: What's wrong with a line in your application's README that says: download and install Python 2.6?  What's wrong with making a two-part MSI where you're MSI installs the Python MSI?

Comment: Because I want a smooth instalation experience ;).

I already have the 2 part setup. The python msi is instaled but is not activated or changed the path. Also, i face the situation where other version of python is already installed.

Comment: Because the end-user are small comapnies. The python scripts are made by developers. Have another step to perform is a barrier in the deployment and I want to avoid it (is like the issue with .net & java)

Comment: If the scripts are by developers then shouldn't they not be scared of installing Python?

Comment: Consider renaming  "How to deploy Python to" -> "How to deploy portable Python 2.7 to" and tag "python" -> "python 2.7". Possibly even Windows -> W7, since W10 released in 2015? With this name a pair of duplicates exist. Old answers here may mislead modern users.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Copy a [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/) folder out of your installer, into the same folder as your Delphi/Lazarus app.  Set all paths appropriately for that.

Comment: I finally do something like this, copyng the full python folder as a subfolder with all the modules preinstaled, then point path to it

Comment: It is surprising how frequently the "simplest thing that could possibly work" turns out to be a viable strategy.

Comment: "Portable Python is not being developed anymore", says their website now. They give alternatives.

Answer (score 13):

You might try using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).  It creates a .exe file with Python already included!

Comment: This not work for me, because is a important part of the product the ability to create plugins in python. Think like if my app is apache and anybody can build their website in python or php.

Comment: I would recommend using Pyinstaller, which does a pretty neat job of creating that .exe file and aggregating all the dependencies (even the python interpreter) into a dist folder of your script. You can check it out [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Also, Pyinstaller supports py3.3+ whereas py2exe fails almost always as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578808/python-indexerror-tuple-index-out-of-range-when-using-py2exe)

Answer (score 4):

Integrate the python interpreter into your Delphi app with [P4D](http://python4delphi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/).  These components actually work, and in both directions too (Delphi classes exposed to Python as binary extensions, and Python interpreter inside Delphi).  I also saw a patch for Lazarus compatibility on the Google Code "issues" page, but it seems there might be some unresolved issues there.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no problem combining .EXE packaging with a tool like PyInstaller or py2exe and Python-written plugins. The created .EXE can easily detect where it's installed and the code inside can then simply `import` files from some pre-determined plugin directory. Don't forget that once you package a Python script into an executable, it also packages the Python interpreter inside, so there you have it - a full Python environment customized with your own code.

Comment: Yep... except that the same tool will be available on osx & linux. So, the best, simpler way is ship .py files.

Comment: I don't understand the context of the comment, mamcx. You can surely use py2exe for all platforms, and the .py plugins need not change.

Comment: According to the website of py2exe is only for windows... or I miss something?

Comment: mamcx, you're right. Then use http://www.pyinstaller.org/ (the first one I mentioned, accidentally, because this is what I use for my code)