# Python Packager

Tags: python

What is the easiest way to package Python programs into stand-alone executables?

Comment: Answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://python-packager.com :-)

Comment: LOL, I've currently been emailing you about your service.

Comment: LOL I know, I'm shameless with the self-plugging. :-/