# How to create exe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)

i have x.pyw file with that i am calling y.py file which is there in another folder,so with that iam able to create exe for x.pyw but that file is not calling y.py,please help me how to create an exe for those both files

Comment: How are you creating the executable? How are you "calling" y.py? And why on earth are you tagging with both [python-2.7] and [python-3.x]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) is the one you want to create exe files of your python programs. However, there are even few other alternatives. This site itself has tons of question on it.

One similar question which will surely help:

[How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)