# Access alternative through python and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, qt, py2exe

is there a way to build a standalone rapid embedded databases with forms as front-end like MS Access, using python and sqlite, by rapid i mean, a WYSIWYG GUI builder for forms (like Access form designer), which should also support subforms,
i search around and it might work with qt designer 4 + python + sqlite,

for the standalone deployment, i heard that you can turn python script to an .exe (for windows) that would rock!!!

my question:
any of you guys tried this? qt designer 4 +python + sqlite, would it replace MS Access?
i know there's Libreoffice base , but it's too big (170~ MB) and requires java -not really a standalone-
I'm pretty good at SQL so i don't care about SQL easy graphical designer

thanks

Comment: For exe, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program  -- Adding most libraries should be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dabo](http://dabodev.com/) or [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) may be what you're looking for, or at least close.