# How can I compile a Pygame program to a Windows .exe

Tags: python, windows, pygame, exe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)

I have found several links talking about what to do, but I am unsure of how to use them. They often say to just use the code, but they don't say if I should put it in the terminal or use it to make a program to run. Many recommend the use of py2exe but when I try to use it it will not run because it says I do not have python 2.6 in my registery. I am rather new to the more complicated side of programming and any help would be appreciated. I am running windows vista.

Comment: 1) Don't use windows vista. Bad. and 2) DO you have py 2.6 installed?

Comment: I thought I did because I searched python 2.6 and it came up, but then I realized that if I type python asdflkj234 it says that too... so I'm not so sure now, I am trying to install python 2.6 now

Comment: I downloaded python 2.6.8 and unzipped it, it is currently on my Desktop. When I tried to run the py2exe installer, it still says that python 2.6.8 is not in my registry. I tried to run the python 2.6.8 setup but it gave me the error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\program\Desktop\Python-2.6.8\setup.py", line 2036, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\program\Desktop\Python-2.6.8\setup.py", line 2031, in main
    'Lib/smtpd.py']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 140, in setup
    raise SystemExit, gen_usage(dist.script_name) + "\nerror: %s" % msg
SystemExit: usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a duplicate question, but I'd recommend using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). We probably need more information on how or why you are failing.

Comment: when I try to run py2exe it tells me that python 2.6 is not found in the registry.

Comment: Is python 2.6 installed?

Comment: I thought I did because I searched python 2.6 and it came up, but then I realized that if I type python asdflkj234 it says that too... so I'm not so sure now, I am trying to install python 2.6 now