# How do I make a Windows exe from a Python 2.7.3 script?

Tags: python

How do I make an executable from Python 2.7.3 scripts? [This](http://www.py2exe.org/) seems to work only on 2.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)

Comment: it is not a duplicate since the question is for 2.7 and above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, py2exe works fine with Python 2.7!!!

PS: If you are not familiar with cmd, you can use a GUI for py2exe.

[Gui2exe](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gui2exe/) also runs with cx_freeze, bbFreeze, py2app, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). They support even Python 3.3.

Comment: You beat me to it, retracting my answer :-)