# running python programs from a CDrom

Tags: python, executable

I have some programs written in python 2.5.4, using the pygame and matplotlib/pyplot libraries on my computer and I want to know whether it is possible to transfer and run python (and the files) from a disc. I tried the drag and drop with both the programs and the python libraries, tools, DLL's, etc. But the programs will not run. Does anyone know how I can get a CD to contain python and run these files?

Answer (score 0):

You must use some tools such as [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

More info can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program) question.

Comment: do you download it directly onto the disc?

Comment: No. But I know, that you can't just copy libraries and DLL's. %)

Comment: So if I aim to have a CD with executable files that can be executed on any computer, where would i install py2exe?

Comment: also what version would i use seeing as I am using python 2.5?

Comment: Please read the documentation available on the proposed links.

Comment: ok got py2exe working for simple programs but the one I need to put onto cd has a button program using Tkinter which links to three other programs that use pyplot and pygame. whenever i try to convert a program that uses pygame i get a dist file with no MyFile.exe but a folder called TCL with no apps within it