# How to compile multiple python scripts to a single python compiled script

Tags: python

I have seven python scripts

```
import nmapper as nmap
import pscan as scan
..
..
etc
```

How it would be possible to make one single python (.pyc) file of all these 7
modules
Note: Whatever I I will import into my 8th script, all I have written.

Comment: Why do they all need to be in one `pyc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all the pyc files in a `.zip` file and rename the extension `.pyc`.

The zip needs to also contain a file `__main__.py`.

See [What is `__main__.py`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042905/what-is-main-py) for more details.

Comment: and sir what about **.exe** extension

Comment: That's a different question, better to ask the whole of [so], not just me. If you search, you'll find, e.g.[How can I make an EXE file from a Python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program)