# python how to build an exe file like scrapy.exe, pip.exe, virtualenv.exe in windows system?

Tags: python

I've found that a lot of python libraries that install have xxx.exe files, such as scrapy.exe, pip.exe, virtualenv.exe, etc. in the Scripts directory. How do they do that?I can't find relevant information, please guide me, thank you very much. By the way, python is installed in the Windows system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). On Windows it can compile to a single `.exe` file.

> PyInstaller bundles a Python application and all its dependencies into
>   a single package. The user can run the packaged app without installing
>   a Python interpreter or any modules. PyInstaller supports Python 2.7
>   and Python 3.4+, and correctly bundles the major Python packages such
>   as numpy, PyQt, Django, wxPython, and others.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I think OP is talking about compiling Cpython packages from source.

Comment: python/Scripts/xxx.exe almost 101KB size, i feel it is not compiled to a single .exe file this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29) you will need Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 which can be downloaded directly from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Alternatively, you could install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) which comes packed with pre-compiled binaries.

Answer (score 1):

i get my answer, it set entry_points ={'console_scripts':['xx'='yy']} in setup.py, when install or package, it can auto build .exe in Scripts directory.

Comment: Thats the correct answer if you are making a PIP package