# How to package a program to share with people?

Tags: python, installation, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a simple program for my friends using some things from the `os` module and a tkinter library called `easygui`. The problem is that I don't want all my friends to have to download Python and easygui in order to use the program.

The point is my friends use Mac OS X and Windows, and I need a way to either package my program with the Python interpreter and the modules that I used to make the program, or an `exe` or `app` file respectively for Windows and Mac.

Comment: Give pyinstaller a try: http://www.pyinstaller.org/ It generally much more pain-free than py2exe or py2app, in my experience. I'm not sure if it works with python3 yet, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bundle a python application including dependencies for windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106725/how-to-bundle-a-python-application-including-dependencies-for-windows)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) and [py2app](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/) for that purpose.

What I haven't done is use them for python 3 apps.

An alternative is [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) which has Python 3 support.

And as Joe said above, [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is another alternative.

Comment: Of all these only cx_freeze seems to support Python 3. Really sad, because cx_freeze wasn't user-friendly at all the last time I tried to use it.

Comment: Thank you for this , I decided to use cx_freeze ... I mean the thing is so easy that if you drag and drop your .py file into the cx_freeze.bat file it will freeze it for you without any settings but still . I love it

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example of use of each of the modules you are suggesting? It easy to say there's this there's that, but an concrete example would help more for future visitors...

Comment: RTFM. All these projects have documentation and tutorials, stackoverflow is not really the place to rehash those.