# How to make a shell script run in Mac when double clicking it?

Tags: macos, shell, executable

I have created a shell script to run a jar file in Mac :

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx512m -jar test.jar;
```

I have renamed this script "**app.command**" to run directly when double clicking it. And i have applied "**chmod +x**" command to it to have executable permissions.

Now when double clicking this script, i get "**Unable to access jarfile test.jar**" while when running this script through Terminal, the jar runs fine !

***Anyone can help me how to make this script run when double click it in Mac ?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run from a terminal, you have a working directory set, and this may not be the case if you double-click it.  Try giving the full path to the jarfile in your script.

Comment: @Curtis: You are right. But is there a way to overcome this ? The jar can be anywhere, but i am sure the shell script will be in the same folder of the jar file ?

Comment: Not sure.  My macs are all at home, and I can't get to them.  I know in Windows, there's a way to set the working directory when you create the shortcut to an application.  Maybe there's something similar on the Mac?  You might have to create a shortcut that runs your script, rather than double-clicking the script directly.

Comment: Okay ... I guess the question now is : "Can i get the absolute path of the current running shell script & use it ?"

Comment: This can get arbitrarily complicated, but if the script is run by double-clicking (and isn't a symbolic link), `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` should work.

Comment: @Gordon ... Thanks a lot .. So how would i use this in my script ? :) ... I know nothing about shell scripting. Example please ?

Comment: Add this command as the second line of the script (i.e. right after `#!/bin/sh` -- that way the rest of the script (mainly the `java` command) will execute from within the script's directory.