# Which tools do I need to create installers multi-platform for my python application?

Tags: python, multiplatform, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An executable Python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app)

imagine that I developed the next killer application in Python using pySide and other several third party libraries.
Which tools do i need to create different installers for every OS out there (windows, osx, nix)?

Answer (score 0):

You may use [CXFreeze](http://www.cxtools.net/default.aspx?nav=cxfrlb) that works on all platforms that Python works. :)