# How to write a python program that automatically starts when windows start?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4, startup

I'm writing a program using python 2.6 and pyqt4. I want this program to automatically start whenever windows stars (something like uTorrent client). How do I make this work? I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just place a shortcut in the "Startup" folder, in the windows start menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can [compile your python script into an exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app) and add it to your startup items: Start > Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Scheduled Tasks