# Is there a way to run a python script that is inside a zip file from bash?

Tags: python, macos, bash, zip, python-module

I know there is a way to import modules which are in a zip file with python. I created kind of custom python package library in a zip file.

I would like to put as well my "task" script in this package, those are using the library. Then, with bash, I would like to call the desired script in the zip file without extracting the zip.

The goal is to have only one zip to move in a specified folder when I want to run my scripts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this. If I create a zip file, I must create `__main__.py` at the root of the zip. Thus, it is possible to launch the script inside the main and call if from bash with the following command :

`python myArchive.zip`

This command will run the `__main__.py` file! :)

Then I can create `.command` file to launch the script with proper parameters.

You can also put some code in the `__main__.py` file to give you more flexibility if you need to pass arguments for example.

ex: `python __main__.py buildProject`

The reference documentation is here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html

Comment: Great. I thought you wanted to arbitrarily call "any" script within your zip archive.

Comment: Basically it is what I wanted, but without unzipping the file. So it's the only way I found to do so.

Comment: I found this [web page](http://www.adaltas.com/en/2018/03/06/execute-python-in-an-oozie-workflow/). You can also run scripts without `__main__.py` like this:
`PYTHONPATH=/path/to/myArchive.zip python -m [filename without extension] [args]`

Comment: Note that one can run any script in the zip archive, that is, `__main__.py` file doesn't have to be in the root of the zip file: `python /path/to/z.zip/path/within/zip`. This can be used  for example to directly run code in a wheel file (which is a zip): `python /path/to/wheel1.whl/module1`. Also, zip files always behave as directories, so one can test this without zip: `python /path/to/any/directory` would run `__main__.py` inside a given directory.

Comment: However, you can't run any file that isn't a `__main__.py` file.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [zipimport](http://docs.python.org/library/zipimport.html). It should work directly from the install. You might have to do some work to make the pythonpath point to your zip file/directory.

> This module adds the ability to import
>   Python modules (*.py, *.py[co]) and
>   packages from ZIP-format archives. It
>   is usually not needed to use the
>   zipimport module explicitly; it is
>   automatically used by the built-in
>   import mechanism for sys.path items
>   that are paths to ZIP archives.that are paths to ZIP archives.

Comment: What I meant was to run python script inside the zip with bash command in order to create a .command file that is launch the desired script. Maybe it's not possible without python?

Comment: I am not aware of anything that could call a script directly inside a zip archive. Sadly, you have to rely on python to read the python scripts which prevents you from using the __main__ == "__main__" idiom.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!
Instead, I'll try to find something to create a application like with my python files. Because in the current situation, I need to have only one file that my users can click and the script run with its modules.

I was thinking about py2app, because I'm on Mac.

Comment: The best link I found for building app with python script :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app

Comment: Contra @Rod, above, @HyunjunKim's comment on @ForceMagic's answer, which deserves to be an answer in its own right, worked just fine for me with a script, one of many in the zip, which uses the `__name__ == "__main__"` idiom.

Comment: @MartinDorey Feel free to create it and put both element of response in there. At the time, I believe only the Rob answer wasn't enough or working out of the box for me.