# How python runs zip files in linux?

Tags: python, linux, zip

I am working with some open-source code and I wanted to make sure I understand what they mean.

They run a command which goes like this:

```
python /some_directory/zipfile.zip "$@"
```

Two questions:
I read about `"$@"`, and I thi

1. Does `"$@"` mean that all arguments which are passed, pass along to the python command?
2. What does the python command run exactly in a zip file? I suspect that it runs a file called __main__.py inside the zip file. Is that true?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. yes, see: https://www.quora.com/What-does-%E2%80%9C-%E2%80%9D-mean-in-Bash.  2 yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760970/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-python-script-that-is-inside-a-zip-file-from-bash/3763360

Answer (score 0):

1. "$@" No, it does't pass along to the python command.
   $@ is special if written in double quotes. Then it will result in a list of quoted
   values, in your case, trusktr, in the three arguments "foo", "bar", and "boo far"
2. yes, its only Runs file called **main**.py inside the zip file.