# How does software (either compiled or interpreted) reach the end user?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An executable Python app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app)

So I have taken a little online python course and I now have an understanding of simple programming. We made our own scrabble game, for example. However what i dont understand is how these .py .c .class or whatever get to an exe form?

I never as an end user have to open .py files ever, with windows it is always .exe, but how are these made? Are they batch files that merely execute the file? But what about dlls?

I guess my question is in any language how is the finished code executed on the machine. When i run a java program i dont have to fiddle with class files i just click an exe.
EDIT......
What i mean isnt how to make python an exe, but how does software get to thatstage full stop. I know interpreted languages go to the interpreter, i guess you use an intermediate language to make an exe which runs the code.

Comment: Yeah, they're compiled. With a special program called a "compiler". I'm not really sure what the question is here. You don't have to sew your own clothes from their constituent pieces of fabric before you put them on in the morning, either.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the code would be compiled into an executable, which may or may not internally contain everything it needs to run.  (If it doesn't, then it could come packaged in an installer which distributes what it needs.)

Specific to Python, a quick Google search turned up [this](http://www.py2exe.org/).  For interpreted languages, since there is really no "compile" step, you'd need some tool to "convert [language] to windows exe" to accomplish what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Most software you run on Windows is not written in an interpreted language like Python, and comes with an installer ('setup.exe') which was generated by some software that creates installers for your code. The purpose of the installer is to both install your program and all the files it may depend on that you have installed as a developer but your end users don't.

See these related questions:

[How can I create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2933/280598)

[py2exe - generate single executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file)

Answer (score 0):

very simply and speaking generically, you would either compile or interpret you source code. An exe or dll would be the result of compilation (JITs as another item to learn about).
You should also learn about "server side" and "client side" code. A web based application would run server side code which may generate html (and perhaps javascript) and send that down to the client side browser.
There are many ways to deploy exe's, dlls etc - simply copy them to the target machine, or use an installer or via a browser plug in environment.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a compiled language that generates native code, the compiler is responsible to generate an executable file based on your source code.

If the language is interpreted, running the program usually means launching the interpreter and passing it the main file of the program. Some languages offer tools to package the interpreter and the sources into an executable.

If the language is compiled but generates intermediate code, you need to run the virtual machine, like an interpreted language. However, if you use .NET on Windows, the compiler generates an executable that loads the virtual machine automatically.