# Change wxpython program's default title and icon in dialog box

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to change the title of my program from its default "Python" to lets say "MyProgram". Also, if I choose "About" from this menu, the dialog box comes up with a picture of the Python logo. How can I change that image?

Pictures for reference:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUFcn.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iJzE.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to create an app bundle with py2app to get that changed. Otherwise it just defaults to Python.

See the following answer:

- [Changing WxPython app Mac menu bar title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633100/changing-wxpython-app-mac-menu-bar-title)

According to that, you will have to also make sure that the plist file is filled out correctly.

Comment: Intending on making it a windows exe, so would py2exe let me do this?

Comment: Yes, I believe all the Windows ones allow you to change that. I believe you can use `SetIcon` for the frame's icon - http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/23/wxpython-embedding-an-image-in-your-title-bar/. I am not sure what About menu you are looking at. A `wx.AboutBox` should be customizable.