# How do I add an "About box" to Mac application, using pyqt and py2app?

Tags: python, cocoa, pyqt, pyqt4, py2app

I'm using PyQt and for packing my application to Mac I'm using py2app.

How do I add an "About Box" to the main menu:

[image]

To look like this example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an about menu there, you just have to add it to the `Help` submenu of your `menuBar()`.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        help_menu = QtGui.QMenu('&Help')
        about = help_menu.addAction('&About')
        about.triggered.connect(self.show_about)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(help_menu)

    def show_about(self):
        print 'shown'

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

The problem is that the title of the application will be `python` and the `About` will be `About python`. To change that, since you already use py2app, you should take look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827430/setting-mac-osx-application-menu-menu-bar-item-to-other-than-python-in-my-pyth)

For PyQt4 it's a little bit different. See the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmenubar.html#qmenubar-on-mac-os-x).

Two relevant things:

1. > Do not call QMainWindow.menuBar() to create the shared menu bar, because that menu bar will have the QMainWindow as its parent. You must create a menu bar that does not have a parent.

   `menuBar =  QtGui.QMenuBar(None)`
2. > The application name is fetched from the Info.plist file (see note below). If this entry is not found no About item will appear in the Application Menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Viktor. I tried you code as is, on a simple project, but the menu didn't show up. What could I be missing?

Comment: @Winston http://i.imgur.com/G1ndBWF.png this is what I get. I clicked the `About python` a few times and you can see that the `shown` is displayed in the console window.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. I'm using Eclipse (and I tried also using Terminal) and PyQt4, but I can't get the same result as you did. This is the result: http://tinyurl.com/aboutboxpyqt

Comment: @Winston Wow, weird... I just tested it and it works with PySide but it does not work with PyQt4.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I'm checking it all!