# pyqt5 default native menu text on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5, qmenubar

Is there a way to change default menu title for native menu on MacOS for a simple pyqt5 app?

[image]

I'm trying to change "Python" menu entry on above image. Is there a way to rename it? Can I hide it somehow?

This code prints only "File":

```
menubar = self.menuBar()
for item in menubar.actions():
    print(item.text())
```

`menubar.setNativeMenuBar(False)` doesn't help too (just move "File" into the MainWindow).

**Update** Sample app code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import sys


class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        # QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName('QtFoo') # doesn't work
        uic.loadUi('App.ui', self)
        self.show()

# app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(["MyCoolApp"])
# app.setApplicationName("QtFoo") # doesn't work
# app.setApplicationDisplayName("Display Name")
window = Ui()
app.exec()
```

Comment: try with: `QtCore.QCoreApplication.setApplicationName("QtFoo")`

Comment: @eyllanesc Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have a try with [`self.setWindowTitle(mytitle)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop) in your `__init__()`.

Comment: @Darkonaut Same result :-(

Comment: @gangabass is the application going to be packaged?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, but right now I just run it with `python3 gui,py` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not willing to package your app, you could create a temporary symbolic link to python as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7880044/9501624). This link can be used to execute python apps while displaying a custom name in the title bar:

[image]

1. go to the location of your app (e.g. my_app.py) file in the terminal
2. create symbolic link (replace location to your python interpreter, replace "BeautifulNaming" with desired name)

   ln -s /Users/Christian/miniconda3/bin/python BeautifulNaming
3. call link to python with your script

   ./BeautifulNaming my_app.py

Answer (score 2):

The "python" in the system menu bar appears because you run the script from the python, as soon as you package the application the title will disappear. For example the following code

```py
# FileName PyQt5MenuProblem.py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow

class AppTest(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("My application")
        self._createMenuBar()

        
    def _createMenuBar(self):
        self.menuBar = self.menuBar()
        self.menuBar.setNativeMenuBar(False)
        fileMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu("&File")
        editMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu("&Edit")
        
        
if __name__== "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    plotWindow = AppTest()
    plotWindow.showMaximized() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

after packaging with

```
pyinstaller --onefile PyQt5MenuProblem.py
```

looks like 
[image]

Key words: MacOS, User Interface, LSUIElement, pyinstaller, pyqt5

Comment: Tip: 1) the `setNativeMenuBar()` is not required in the scope of the question, I'd remove it as it might lead to confusion making think that it might be a requirement; 2) using the `-w` switch in pyinstaller should ensure that the appropriate .app bundle is created, which will correctly create the correct plist file that will make the menu title correct (theoretically based on `windowTitle()` in that case, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I planned to award this answer my bounty too but unfortunately there is no way to award more than one answer :-(