# REALbasic array in an array

Tags: php, arrays, realbasic, xojo

I am trying to write a soap parameter in **REALbasic**.

I need to add an array within another array similar to this in **php**:

```
 $params = array(array(
     'sku' => 'some sku'
 ));
```

so I can pass this:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.list', $params);
```

I have

```
  dim aArgs  (0,1) as String
  dim aParmas  (0,1) as String
  aArgs(0,0)="sku"
  aArgs(0,1)="some sku"
  aParmas(0,1)= aArgs
```

But receive a "`Type mismatch error.  Expected String, but got String(,)`"

How can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, the line

```
aParmas(0,1)= aArgs
```

is wrong because you assign an array (which is in aArgs) to a single element of aParmas. And since those single elements hold a String, you try to assign an array to a single string here, hence the error message.

But I think you're looking at this from the wrong end. You need to start with figuring out what parameters you need to send *to* the session function you want to call.

That means: You need to find the REALbasic function for `$client->call`. Once you know which function that is, look at the parameters that function expects. I doubt it expects a two-dimensional array for the "params". Once you know what to pass here, let us know if you still cannot figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

An explanation of multidimensional arrays in REALbasic is [here](http://kknapp.sd38.bc.ca/IT_Tutorial_Units/REALbasic/16.html#section3)

The short answer is that you **can't** have a PHP-like array of arrays. You need to wrap your array in a class and make the class behave like an array.

Any reason you're using REALbasic? If it's cross-platform you're after, `python` is ALWAYS a better choice

Comment: The solution is correct, but the assertion that python is "ALWAYS" better is very subjective.

Comment: In this case I stand by the assessment. A huge community, superior documentation, pythonic readability. I have used both languages extensively and would like to hear arguments otherwise.

Comment: Just getting started with python and making a compiled app is much more complicated than the Xojo workflow of simply selecting a platform and pressing Build. While Python might be better in many cases, there are plenty of situations where it would be easier and quicker to do the same thing in Xojo. For instance, there is need for a topic like this for Xojo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/an-executable-python-app