# How to convert my python project to binary

Tags: python-2.7

We have developed small project which uses mysql connection through python.

We would like to know how can I generate the binary for the project, which I can directly use to execute from any system

Tried pyinstaller, but not helping

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See if this helps: [How can I create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python)