# packaging django application and deploying it locally

Tags: python, django

I've never worked with Django before so forgive me if a question sounds stupid.

I need to develop a web application, but I do not want to deploy it on a server. I need to package it, so that others would "install" it on their machine and run it. Why I want to do it this way? There are many reasons, which I don't want to go into right now. My question is: can I do it? If yes, then how?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python and linked

Comment: Use docker to allow you to share a preconfigured image

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. However, the client machine would need to be equipped with the correct technologies for this to work.

When you launch a web app on a server (live), the server is required to have certain settings and installs. For example, a Django web app: the server must have a version of Django installed.

Hence, whichever machine is running your web app, must have Django installed. It presumably also needs to have the database too. It might be quite a hassling process but it's possible.

Just like as a developer, you may have multiple users working on 1 project. So, they all need to have that project 'installed' on their devices so they can run it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a python to executable program, with Django already in it. The website files you can place into the dist folder or whatever folder has the executable in it. Then you can compress it and share it with others (who have the same OS as you).

For an example:

You have this script in Django (I'm too lazy to actually write one), and you want to share it with someone who doesn't have Python and Django on his/her computer.