# I would like to make my file an executable however it wont run unless its using python?

Tags: python, executable

I have a calendar build with tkcalendar and i want to make it an executable file that i can send for people to test out and give me feedback.
However i cant seem to run it unless i am using python.

I tried py2exe and pyinstaller

```
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
from inputs import *
from quickstart import *
from Customization import *
from importlib import reload 
try: 
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    import datetime
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk


Button_Light = ttk.Button(root,text='Light Style', command=Main_Body_white)
Button_Dark = ttk.Button(root,text='Dark Style', command=Main_Body_Black)
enter_button2 = Button(root, text="Make-Event", command=Create)

Button_Dark.pack()
Button_Light.pack()
enter_button2.pack()
```

So this code works 100% but it wont open unless in python. This code grabs many different modules and combines them to create the final result

[image: File that contains all the code for the program]

I think because This code relies heavily on GUI and thats where the issue is happening.

[image: The Gif show the problem i am having]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

---

[image]

Still no luck But this might explain better. As you can see the code does run in cmd. But it dosent RUN the GUI part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: I read that but none of the options worked for me

Comment: might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python

Comment: yea i read on almost everything already. My issue is specific because i think the amount if gui i have is messing with the executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the module `pip install auto-py-to-exe`, it is working for me, after installing type `auto-py-to-exe` in python prompt command line auto-py-to-exe window will appear. Put `input()` at the end of your python script and then select your script location, do not change output folder destination, after making executable open output folder, copy or cut the .exe application and paste it anywhere outside C drive. It'll work without using python. auto-py-to-exe window image attached for your reference.
[image]

Comment: This was the closest, It worked for most part but i got a module babel.numbers not found. will look into that now

Comment: Use `pip install Babel` and restart your terminal & auto-py-to-exe window and then try

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel.numbers'

Comment: Go to this link https://github.com/python-babel/babel/blob/master/babel/numbers.py and copy the script in Babel folder and then try

Comment: still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make 1 folder and paste all files there:

Then you need to paste your folder to python directory where python install
to make sure to paste in the script folder

In My case python is install on this directory:

```
C:\Users\Hamza Lachi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts
```

and then type this command:

```
pyinstaller -w -F '.\file_name.py'
```

It Will Converts python file into exe file

Why Exe Can't Run:

if you link files to python file that's why your python script is not working so you need to paste that files! in exe directory

For Example:

If You Link images so if script not working so you need to copy images in exe directory

**SOLUTION**

Copy all files in exe directory