# Python executable binary for Linux from Windows OS

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

My Development environment is Windows and the production is on Linux. How can I build an executable python file on Windows machine and can run it on Linux as well?

Comment: Use a virtual machine.  Or WSL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python)