# Convert Python File to Linux Executable File in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

Currently, I am in the process of creating a programming language in Python, but when using Pyinstaller in Windows, it only provides me with an executable file that can only be used in Windows operating systems, but Linux returns an error like this:

```py
bash: ./main.exe: Permission denied
```

I have been looking for ways to convert Python into an executable file for Linux under Windows such as `cxfreeze`, `nuitka`, `py2exe` and more of those. Please I need some help!!

Comment: This is not directly your question but leads you to some extend in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python
The excepted answer describes very well which package is for which environment.

Comment: Wait! Wait! Then why I cannot use exe file from Pyinstaller on Windows in Linux??

Comment: Windows Executalbe are windows exclusive. You need to build for windows with py2exe and for linux with freeze.

Comment: You have to build independently, windows and linux/unix system are fundamental different. So for Windows `py2exe`, for linux `freeze` and `py2app` for Mac. Pyinstaller does not cross-compile, like mentioned here: https://pyinstaller.org/en/v6.3.0/index.html?highlight=it%20is%20not%20a%20cross-compiler#pyinstaller-manual

Answer (score -1):

nstall VirtualBox or another virtualization software on your Windows machine.

Create a Linux virtual machine (VM) within VirtualBox.

Install a Linux distribution (e.g., Ubuntu) on the VM.

Transfer your Python code to the Linux VM. You can use shared folders or any method you prefer.

Install PyInstaller on the Linux VM: